# Laravel 5.4 controller doesn`t show page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have folder "*aboutus*" which contains '*index.blade.php*' file and folder "*thanks*".
Folder "*thanks*"contains also '*index.blade.php*'

My route for both of them:

```html
    Route::resource('admin/aboutus', 'AdminAboutusController',['names'=>[

        'index'=>'admin.aboutus.index',
        'create'=>'admin.aboutus.create',
        'store'=>'admin.aboutus.store',
        'edit'=>'admin.aboutus.edit'
    ]]);

    Route::resource('admin/aboutus/thanks', 'AboutThanksController',['names'=>[

        'index'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.index',
        'create'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.create',
        'store'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.store',
        'edit'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.edit'
    ]]);
```

I have created controller for *aboutus* and *thanks* separately (AdminAboutusController and AboutThanksController)

***AdminAboutusController*** index funnction returns view which i am able to see

```html
public function index() { return view('admin.aboutus.index'); }
```

But controller ***AboutThanksController*** doesn`t shows me my page, it shows me white blank

```html
public function index() { return view('admin.aboutus.thanks.index'); }
```

on *php artisan route:list* i can see that route is aviable.
Why it happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have `admin.aboutus.thnx.index` Thanks Vs Thnx :)

Comment: @MihirBhende thank you that you noticed) sorry, it was misspelling, i changed it it real one) it was bad idea not to copy from code that small part)

Comment: since `aboutus` is a resource with possibily show. I may think you have an url like this: `admin/aboutus/{aboutus}` registered. When you hit `admin/aboutus/thanks` you would hit `admin/aboutus/{aboutus}` can you make `php artisan route:list` to confirm ?

Comment: @cbaconnier you are right, i checked it,  index was as  `{aboutus}`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `thanks` route above `about us` route

```
Route::resource('admin/aboutus/thanks', 'AboutThanksController',['names'=>[

    'index'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.index',
    'create'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.create',
    'store'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.store',
    'edit'=>'admin.aboutus.thanks.edit'
]]);
Route::resource('admin/aboutus', 'AdminAboutusController',['names'=>[

    'index'=>'admin.aboutus.index',
    'create'=>'admin.aboutus.create',
    'store'=>'admin.aboutus.store',
    'edit'=>'admin.aboutus.edit'
]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer to close the question:

You have `admin.aboutus.thnx.index` but your folder is `admin/aboutus/thanks/index`

Please change to `admin.aboutus.thanks.index` and it should work

Comment: Where do you mean it should be replaced? I tried to set everywhere `admin/aboutus/thanks/index` but it was not working

Answer (score 0):

using `route:list` you are able to see list of routes but `return view()` function don't take route as a parameter. You have to give the file name and path.For example you  want to show `thanks.blade.php` file which is inside admin/aboutus of your view folder. So you have to write:

```
return view('admin.aboutus.thanks');
```